# Context free grammar for $L = \{w \text{ | }w \in \{a,b\}^*, |w|_a=|w|_b-1\}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I'm trying to find a grammar for $L = \{w \text{ | }w \in \{a,b\}^*, |w|_a=|w|_b-1\}$, which is proving to be tricky.

I know that $L_2 = \{w \text{ | }w \in \{a,b\}^*, |w|_a=|w|_b\}$ has the following one, so I have been trying to modify it so that I "force" to have one more $b$, but I don't see how to do this. The obvious choice would be to replace $\epsilon$ with $b$, but that would potentially get two more $b$'s. Is there a trick for this one?

$$\begin{align}
  S &\to \epsilon \\
  S &\to aSbS \\
  S &\to bSaS \enspace.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for a trick. Yes, there is a construction to add a single letter to the strings in the language of a grammar given in advance.

For simplicity I will start with a grammar in Chomsky Normalform, i.e., every rule is of the form $A\to BC$ or $A\to \sigma$, with $A,B,C$ variables and $\sigma$ terminal.

Assume there is a context-free grammar $G$ for a language $L$ then we can construct a grammar for "strings in $L$ with an extra $b$" in a generic way. We use the variables to hand down the instruction "add a $b$" to one of their successors. For each variable $A$ we introduce a copy $A_1$ that carries this task.

Thus, for every rule $A\to BC$ we add the new rules $A_1\to B_1C$ and $A_1\to BC_1$. Morever, we make it possible to add the extra $b$, with rules $A_1 \to bA$. Now starting with $S_1$ derivations are as before, except at some point in the derivation a single $b$ is introduced. Note that we need to generate a $b$ since variables $A_1$ cannot be rewritten into terminals. One tiny detail: the $b$ can only be introduced *before* a variable, so in order to append a $b$ we need the additional rule $S_1\to Sb$. (We need no other additional rules since a $b$ after a variable can be replaced by a $b$ before another variable, except at the end.)

Comment: @Lightsong, this answer, simple and powerful, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Wow, that's really clever. Thank you! As @JohnL. said, I will be marking this one as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply consider the following grammar: $$ S\to S_1 b S_1$$ where $S_1$ is the start variable of a grammar for the language of words $w$ with $|w|_a = |w|_b$. Correctness is self-explanatory.

So using the grammar you wrote, you get the following grammar:
$$ S\to T b T$$

$$ T \to aTbT| bTaT | \epsilon$$

Comment: I see, that was...simple. Thank you! Going with that construction, I guess $$ S\to S_1 b S_1 b S_1$$ would for example give $L = \{w \text{ | }w \in \{a,b\}^*, |w|_a=|w|_b-2\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. It should be easy to prove. Clearly, every generated word is in the language. Also, every word in the language has at least two b's: pick two b's and generate everything in between, before, and after them using $S_1$

Comment: great, thank you :)

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi Although I believe the grammar for two extra $b$'s in the comments is correct, I do not think it is as simple as "*pick two b's and generate everything in between*". Note that the two $b$'s have to be chosen such that the between, before and after parts have an equal numbers of $a$'s and $b$'s.

Comment: You're right. I missed that.